# PHP Post variables don't work anymore

Tags: php, post

Ok so I have a very basic form, that used to work.

```
<form action="index.php#enquiry" method="post" id="quickform">
  <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="yes">
  <label class="labels">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="reqname" name="reqname" /><br/>
  <label class="labels">Tel</label>
  <input type="text" class="validate[required] input" name="num" id="valiphone" /><br/>
  <label class="labels">Email</label>
  <input type="email" class="custom[email] input" name="useremail" id="valiemail" />       
  <label class="labels">Enquiry</label>
  <textarea id="textarea" rows="7" name="messtxt" class="validate[required]"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent" id="sendButton" >
    <img src="images/send.png" alt="submit" />
  </button>
</form>
```

This self submits, and when reloaded should hit a simple php if statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

Do thing A

}else{

Do thing B

}
```

Thing A never gets executed.

I know it self submits and hits the PHP because I can echo a string

I've done this a million times, and I am 100% sure this script worked a couple of days ago, so unless i've typod something and can't see it by accident. Is there something that could of gone wrong where pages don't post? server wise or anything? I've noticed similar problems with an upload script I had.

Comment: You have unclosed textarea tag

Comment: was a copy and paste error, its closed on the actual script and corrected the question

Comment: try running a var_dump() on $_POST and see what you get.  That'll at least tell you if nothing's getting POSTED at all or if something else is wrong.

Comment: I've been thinking that so many times and it always turns out to be a mistake i made somewhere anyhow. Try and give os some of your php code.

Comment: `class="validate[required] input"` seems weird to me. In PHP, `[]` is treated as an array input. I for one, don't understand how your script works. Some explanation would be nice. As is your `index.php#enquiry`; most bizarre.

Comment: Read my answer, it is helpful

Comment: var_dump($_POST); = array(0) { } // var_dump($_POST['submit']); = NULL

Comment: add name='submit' to button submit. I don't see any item have name like submit in your form

Comment: The hidden field has that name... try my answer

Comment: so it looks like nothing got posted.  Try changing the action to "index.php" instead of "index.php#enquiry".  I'm unsure if that'll help but it seems off.

Comment: @Fred class="validate[required] input" is just from a validation plugin I use, [] can be used to set variables of sorts, required, email etc etc. Used countless times with no issues, index.php#enquiry was to jump to a certain div on self-submission.

Comment: i changed it back to just index.php but no change, i remember it working, i have the test logs from it in all browsers, and suddenly just seems to of stopped

Comment: @TryingToBeZen ok, thanks for clearing that up. Now, why does `type="text" class="validate[required] input"` have `input` tacked on, and not `name="messtxt" class="validate[required]"`? Just pickin' at straws here. Make a difference? And maybe the fact that your `submit` is hidden, might be playing tricks on you. The problem may lie in your unshown code, where your `if...else` is. Baffled.

Comment: I don't know what's really going on but the next thing I'd try without seeing your full code and dumping it into a fresh page would be to enable error reporting with these two statements... `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and `error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: @Fred I have two classes on it, the validate class for the JQuery plugin and the input is a CSS styling thing. I removed all validation and it still didn't work

Comment: Yeah, make sure your JS isn't doing anything crazy like stopping the action on the form and/or manipulating it in one way or another.

Comment: @TryingToBeZen Try to set your `isset($_POST['submit']` to something else, like the `email` field for instance. And what did a `var_dump()` produce, if you did do one? I think it's the fact that your `submit` is hidden.

Comment: could a .htaccess file effect it?

Comment: I just tested your code and it works well. You should check the other HTML/JS code you have on the page, probably you have some interaction

Comment: @fred var dump result above

Comment: @TryingToBeZen Many things could affect it, why not .htaccess? Gawd, your `php.ini` could be the culprit, who knows without seeing your full code. I'm out of options.

Comment: @Fred the rest of the code is just a PDO statement, i Know that works. But even if all that was inside the if statement was an echo I still can't hit that

Comment: My .htaccess to remove the .php was the problem, first time i've used one. taking it it effectively meant the form action was invalid? Sorry all.

Comment: @TryingToBeZen Good stuff. Glad to hear it.

Comment: LOL there should be a comical downvote button next to the productive one, just for times like these.  Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `.htaccess` file. Might be the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

PHP $_POST assumes that the data entered in the brackets is the name of the element. In your case you have not named your submit button "submit", which is what you are telling PHP... 
Simply change the button to this:

```
<button type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent" id="sendButton" name="submit">
    <img src="images/send.png" alt="submit" />
</button>
```

I just added `name="submit"`. You also should get rid of your hidden input named submit. This should solve the problem!

Comment: Read my edit... I cover that too... Now it seems like a different problem. Thx for pointing that out!